# Google places: Ignore historic names that are more than X years old

Tags: google-places-api

I am using the Google places API in an enterprise product. When I search for, let's say, a European dictator from 1933 to 1945, I find lot's of places that used to bear his name. All these places were renamed in the mid- to late 1940's.

Having these matches show up for our Enterprise customers is not a show-stopper (we're all adults, after all), but it does not feel right.

Is there a way to limit the matches to a more recent history? In other words, can I tell the Google places API to ignore historical names that are more than 10 years old?

Comment: Could you please file a feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188872&template=789309)?